# Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I would like to assign the value 1 to the word "retail" and the value 0 for the word "wholesale". So if I can multiply cell (A1*.08)* retail/wholesale so if B1 has has the word retail the value of C1 will be "A1*.08" and if B1 has the word wholesale the value of C1 will be "0". Sorry if I worded this odd im a noob :/

Comment: 10 second google search..... https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Comment: Thank you anyway but i figured it out. But for anyone with the same question =(A1*0.08)*((IF(B1= "retail" ,1))+(IF(B1 = "wholesale" ,0)))

Comment: From the tag: "Questions about Google Spreadsheets are off topic and should be asked on webapps.stackexchange.com,"

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in cell C1:

```
=IF(LOWER(B1)="wholesale",0,IF(LOWER(B1)="retail",A1*0.8,NA()))
```

This checks:

`=IF(LOWER(B1)="wholesale"` - If B1 in lowercase is "wholesale" (In case any of it is in uppercase, otherwise it won't match), then...

`0` - Just return zero. Otherwise...

`IF(LOWER(B1)="retail"` - If B1 to lower is "retail", then...

`A1*0.8` - Return A1 * 0.8. If it's not wholesale OR retail....

`NA()` - Return a N/A error, we didn't find retail OR wholesale so we don't know what to do.